# Laravel does not return withInput() form value

Tags: php, laravel

```
$languages = Languages::where("status","=", 1)->get();
   
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'PageLanguage.title.*' => 'required',
    ],[
        "required" => "her 3 formu yenden nezerden kecirdin zehmeet olmasa"

    ]);
    
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('admin/page/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)

    }
```

Comment: Where you've included the form values? I don't see withInput() any where.

Answer (score 1):

I tried withInput() function and it works like that

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('admin/page/create')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(); 

}
```

and blade file should be:

{!! Form::text('name', old('name'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}